# are IoC containers singletons or static?

Tags: java, oop, inversion-of-control

I'd like to better understand how IoC containers work and code up something to use for myself. Is there a best practice when creating the class for the container? Is it a singleton? is it static? Is it not a singleton but just has a bunch of static properties to hold resolved objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IoC containers I know of are neither static nor singletons and I can't see any good reasons to make them. Just make it a normal class and create instances of it. There are scenarios where you might want to use several instances to separate independent concerns.

As you want to keep your components agnostic of the container, i.e. don't make them reference the container. If your component (the object which is being resolved by the container) needs to be able to access the container to get new instances, you would usually abstract an interface for this (commonly referred to as [Service Locator Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) (.NET, but it's all the same)), and let the container inject itself into the component. Again, no reason for static classes or methods.

One very good reason to follow this practice is that you are able to exchange the container implementation, for example switch to a 'professional' IoC framework, without touching your components at all.

Apart from that, there are a number of restrictions for static classes and methods in general, which you usually don't want, especially not when your system is likely to be changed, to grow and to get complex. To mention two: Static classes can't implement interfaces. Consequently you can never mock your container for testing purposes; Every usage of the container requires a fixed reference to the container assembly rather than to a contract. You cant subclass a static class;

Comment: many IoC containers allow you to mark a class as a singleton. Whenever you ask the container for an object of that class, it looks to see if that object has been created before and gives the already created object back. How do you accomplish that, across multiple classes, without passing the IoC object around into every object created?

Comment: The instance of the singleton 'service' is only shared in the scope of the one container instance. Using more than one container only make sense if each has its very own domain to work in without any interdependency. In a normal application you create one container in a bootstrapping sequence, mostly right after startup and from then on you use this instance to resolve everything.

Comment: ah i see. I'm developing for Android. I guess this is why there are already DI frameworks because Android creates some objects for you of which you have little control.

Comment: I don't know anything about Android, sorry.. It doesn't take much to build a simple IoC container, but it does to build a proper one for production. It's perfectly fine to build your own to get started with the topic, but don't make it static ;) There are a couple of general restrictions on static classes and methods, that you just don't want on a class for which maintenance is crucial, i.e. testability, inheritance or losing the ability to use interfaces for the container at all.